# How to convert data class to map

Tags: json, spring, kotlin

I tried convert to data class to map. (Under the code is just example code)

```
data class User (
  val name : String = "",
  val age : Int = 0,
  val deviceGroup: MutableSet<DeviceGroup> = mutableSetOf()
)
data class DeviceGroup (
  val name : String = "",
  val deviceLink : MutableSet<DeviceLink> = mutableSetOf()
)
data class DeviceLink (
  val id : Int = 0,
  val device : Device
)
data class Device (
  val devId : Int = 0,
  val name : String = ""
)

fun main (request : HttpServletRequest) {
  val currentUser = request.session.getAttribute("user") as User
  val data = userRepository.findByName(currentUser.name)
  
  // return currentUser
  // result is {name="test", age=17, deviceGroup = [{name="group1"}, {name="group2"}]}
  
  // I want deserialization data class to Map
  val response = data.deviceGroup.toMap()
  
  response.deivceGroup.forEach {
    // And add new key, pair
    it.add(Map<String, MutableSet<Device>>("devices", mutableSetOf()))

    // Lastly, I want put in the value    
deviceGroupRepository.findByName(it.name).deviceLink.forEach {
      it.devices.add(this)
    }
  }
  
  return response
}
```

if just return the data value, that's result is "{name="test", age=17, deviceGroup = [{name="group1"}, {name="group2"}]}"

How to convert to data class to Map object and add new key pair?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Use `associate` to turn a collection into a Map

The Kotlin standard library provides a function called [`associate`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate.html) which will take a collection of objects and transform them into a map. It takes one argument, which is a function specifying what the keys and values of the map should be.

For example, in your case, you would call it like this:

```kotlin
val response = data.deviceGroup.associate { it.name to it.deviceLink }
```

It will return a `Map<String, MutableSet<DeviceLink>>` where the key is the `name` of the device group and the value is the `deviceLink` set.

---

The easiest way to add new values is simply to append them with the `+` operator.

```kotlin
val response = data.deviceGroup.associate { 
    it.name to it.deviceLink 
} + mapOf("device" to emptySet())
```

If you need more control than that, you could use `.toMutableMap()` so new entries can be added using `put`.

```kotlin
val response = data.deviceGroup.associate { 
    it.name to it.deviceLink 
}.toMutableMap()
response.put("device", emptySet())
```

Comment: You just create a map manually... How to serialize an object to map automatically?